# Searching Logs on multiple machines

Tags: logging, production-environment

Does anyone know of a good tool that allows you to tail and search through log files that are spread across a cluster of machines.  We have multiple web servers and app servers and digging through the logs on each server one by one is a pain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following bash script (if you can ssh to the remote machines and have read access to the log files)

(echo "machine1"; ssh machine1 tail /var/log/messages; echo "machine2"; ssh machine2 tail /var/log/messages;) | less

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much work it is to install/configure, but I've heard a few good things about [splunk](http://www.splunk.com/). YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Splunk is very effective at aggregating log files for searching and displaying the results as a graph of the counts of the hits by time but it is also expensive. I recently learned about [Kibana](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/future-of-work/processing-performance-data-with-kibana-64867) which is an open source alternative to splunk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/) to tail several hosts and grep all results:

```
$ fab -P -u 'USER' -p 'PASSWORD' --linewise -H host1,host2,host3 -- tail -f /path/to/my/log.log | grep ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a small shell script :

- define your parameters:

```
machines=("user@address1" "user@address2" "user@address3")
log_files=("/path/to/application.log" "/path2/to2/application.log" "/path3/to3/application.log" "/path4/to4/application.log")
```

- tail every machine and wait for interruption:

```
#!/bin/bash

pids_arr=()
for ((i=0;i<${#machines[@]};++i)); do
    ssh "${machines[$i]}" "tail -f ${log_files[$i]}" & pids_arr+=("$!")
done

pids="${pids_arr[*]}"
trap "kill -9 $pids" SIGINT SIGKILL
for pid in ${pids}; do wait $pid; done
trap - SIGINT SIGKILL
```

*extra: if you don't want to see the job monitor logs, you can use:*

```
job_mon=${-//[^m]/} ; set +m

(...)

sleep 0 ; if [[ -n "$job_mon" ]]; then set -m; else set +m; fi
```